# Which FOSS RDBMS to use for geospatial data?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, geocoding

I'm developing an application using Google Maps API. The goal is to geocode certain locations and then allow users to search for these locations based on which ones are nearest to the user (e.g. "Thing x is 20 miles from you").

In MySQL, I can just store the geo-coordinates and use haversine formula to do the distance calculations. Someone has suggested I consider Postgres because it has "better support for geographical data."

So, the question is: what are the pros and cons of using MySQL or Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has support for what you are talking about on board. But for a lot more functionality (and for what the "someone" you mention was probably thinking about) turn to **PostGIS**.

See the [home page](http://postgis.net/), [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/), or start at good old [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS) for an overview.

#### Edit after question in comment:

In particular, see the [function support matrix](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch08.html#PostGIS_TypeFunctionMatrix) to get an impression what PostGIS can do for you.
Computing the **distance between two points** is a standard feature. You can have that for a variety of data types. Which data type to use? See this [question in the FAQ](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/PostGIS_FAQ.html#id2622023) and further links there.

Comment: Yes, but what are the pros and cons of each solution? Isn't MySQL enough for what I need?

Comment: I don't know enough about the geo-capabilities of MySQL. PostGIS certainly is.

Comment: What I need to do is be able to compute the distances between geo coordinates. I can implement haversine in MySQL. What does PostGIS do for me in this regard?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: I amended my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just points, MySQL is fine. If you have more complex geometries, like delivery routes, or cell reception areas, or whatever, you want PostGIS, because it supports more sophisticated indexing of geometric data (r-trees). MyISAM is actually better than InnoDB for spatial data, BTW, because it also supports r-tree spatial indexes (but not as powerful queries as PostGIS.) If you just need points, though, InnoDB or MyISAM b-trees are adequate. If bounding boxes are enough (ie, you need everything within a rectangular plane around some point), then geohash-based indexes are ok. More background on all that [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves). It is well worth the trouble getting familiar with PostGIS and Postgres, they are both remarkably good projects and by far my preferred relational db, but just looking up points does not require them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check the [MonogDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), it supports geospatial indexing letting you query for nearest objects very effectively ! Thats what the guys at Foursquare using to find nearest venues ...

Comment: Sure, nice to have another option. But what benefit does this give me over using MySQL + haversine?

Comment: If you plan to have a lot of entries to this particular table without doing a joins with other tables while querying, the MongoDB is probably the fastest solution.

Comment: Fastest because it is faster than MySQL when computing the distances between geocoordinates? Do you have some benchmarks you can refer me to?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i think it depends a lot on the initial setup of your app.